# how to enter data into the database?

Tags: c#

This is where I have reached in trying to add data into my access database using C#. Now when I run  the application I get an error saying Insert Into statement is wrong . How do I proceed now?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace Santosh
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                        if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Plz Specify the UserName & Password","ERROR",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else if (textBox2.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Plz Specify the Password", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else if (textBox3.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Plz RE Enter the Password", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\leelakrishnan\Desktop\database1.accdb";
               String uname, pass;
               string id;
               id =  textBox1.Text;
                uname = textBox2.Text;
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(uname);
                pass = textBox3.Text; 
                OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                myConnection.Open();
                int i=107;
                string query = @"insert into EMPLOYEE_TABLE (ID,UserName,Password) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";

                //string query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (ID,UserName,Password) VALUES (i,'uname',' pass')";
                i++;

                OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();// new OleDbCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = query;

                //TODO: Review the datatypes and lengths for these parameters
                OleDbParameter myParm = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar,50);
                myParm.Value = textBox1.Text;

                myParm = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
                myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;

                myParm = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
                myParm.Value = textBox3.Text;


                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();


                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User Account Succefully Created", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't say why the insert statement is wrong? I'm pretty sure you need to replace the values in the query with @id, @uname, @pass

Comment: @shoban can you help me with whats wrong in this coding ?

Comment: @Austin This is the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: it would be helpful to see the error in its entirety, message, etc.

Comment: @Ivanov Its says OLDb Exception Unhandled and Syntax Error in Insert Into Statement

Comment: @Everyone I went and commented the line MyCommand.ExecuteNonQery(); then it displays User Account Successfully Added.(Message)

Comment: and when i see the database nothing is added into it plz help

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as though you've parameterized your command (good work!), you should probably next start with writing a parameterized query:

```
string query = @"insert into EMPLOYEE_TABLE (ID,UserName,Password) VALUES (@id, @uname, @pass)";
```

Comment: I don't know much about MS Access query syntax anymore, but have you tested the query against the DB using some other query tool?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some extraneous quotes in your string.  When you use parameters there's no reason for a quote in the string at all--and parameters are absolutely required in a situation like this because someday you'll hire somebody Irish.  (The non-parameterized version will crash and burn on Mr. O'Neill.)

Use the debugger and look at the command text just before the ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass [variables](http://www.richquackenbush.com/2011/02/bind-variables.html) into the command, but you're not declaring them in the sql statement.

Try doing this:

```
string query = @"insert into EMPLOYEE_TABLE (ID,UserName,Password) VALUES (@id, @uname, @pass)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as though you've parameterized your command (good work!), you should probably next start with writing a parameterized query:

string query = @"insert into EMPLOYEE_TABLE (ID,UserName,Password) VALUES ('@id', '@uname', '@pass')"; Make sure you incase the VARCHAR values with Apstrophe's